# Android DOM Parsing - Converting pubDate tag

Tags: android, dom, datetime, xml-parsing

im using DOM Parser to parse this XML feed : http://loc.grupolusofona.pt/index.php/?format=feed

It's working fine, parsing all the fields i need, but i wanted to convert the result got from tag pubDate from "Wed, 31 Oct 2012 17:12:42 +0000" to "2 Days Ago, at 17:12" or something like this.

How can i do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have been trying Joda-Time but with no success.. however Christian's solution just got me on track, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code you need:

```
String dateString = "Wed, 31 Oct 2012 12:12:42 +0100";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
Date date = null;
try {
    date = sdf.parse(dateString);
    String timeOfDay = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(date);
    java.sql.Timestamp timeStampDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    java.sql.Timestamp timeStampNow = new Timestamp((new java.util.Date()).getTime());

    long secondDiff = timeStampNow.getTime() / 1000 - timeStampDate.getTime() / 1000;
    int minuteDiff = (int) (secondDiff / 60);
    int hourDiff = (int) (secondDiff / 3600);
    int dayDiff = daysBetween(date, new Date()) - 1;
    if (dayDiff > 0) {
        System.out.println("Posted " + dayDiff + " days ago @ " + timeOfDay);
    } else if (hourDiff > 0) {
        System.out.println("Posted " + hourDiff + " hour(s) ago @ " + timeOfDay);
    } else if (minuteDiff > 0) {
        System.out.println("Posted " + minuteDiff + " minute(s) ago @ " + timeOfDay);
    } else if (secondDiff > 0) {
        System.out.println("Posted " + secondDiff + " second(s) ago @ " + timeOfDay);
    }
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

daysBetween:

```
public static int daysBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    int daysBetween = 0;
    while (startDate.before(endDate)) {
        startDate.setTime(startDate.getTime() + 86400000);
        daysBetween++;
    }
    return daysBetween;
}
```

Output:
Posted 2 days ago @ 12:12

Comment: Perfect! Well, almost, don't know why you put -1 when calculating daysBetween, i take it off and works fine :)